# FBLoginView delegate methods not called anymore

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using the `FBLoginView` (version 3.xx) in my app to automatically create useraccounts based on their Facebook profile, but the delegate callbacks of `FBLoginViewDelegate` don't get called anymore.

My code is as folloows:

In the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of my `AppDelegate` I have this line:

```
[FBLoginView class];
```

I have a class called `LoginHandler` that conformes to the `FBLoginViewDelegate` protocol and which implements these methods:

```
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
- (void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error
```

In the `viewDidLoad` method of my view controller I have this code:

```
self.fbLoginView.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
self.fbLoginView.delegate = [LoginHandler sharedInstance];
```

I also have set up my Info.plist with:

```
FacebookAppID (containing <my-app-id>)
FacebookDisplayName (containing my app name=
CFBundleURLSchemes (containing fb<my-app-id>)
```

When I press the Facebook login button it switches over to the Facebook app, asks about the permisions (only the first time) and returns to my app. However, none of the delegate methods get called at this point. This used to work before and I did get callbacks for both `loginViewShowingLoggedInUser` and `loginViewFetchedUserInfo`, but some time ago it stopped working and I simply can't figure out what changes have broken it.
An interesting thing is that every time I start the app (before I do anything with the Facebook button) my `loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser` gets called. I don't know if it is related to my issue or if this is normal behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer. I needed to override this method in my app delegate.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    // Call FBAppCall's handleOpenURL:sourceApplication to handle Facebook app responses
    BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

    // You can add your app-specific url handling code here if needed
    return wasHandled;
}
```

Comment: I tried putting a break-point in this method, and it is simply not getting hit.

Comment: OK, i FINALLY figured it out. I had to update my plist settings so that the app runs in the  background. Man that was tough.